# Change DIV Image Style with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I change `#win img` styling with javascript? I want to change the style to: `max-width: 40%; max-height: 40%;` using javascript or jQuery.

```
#win img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="win" align="center" style="width: auto; margin-top: 30px; height: auto; max-width: 80%; max-height: 80%; overflow: auto;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("win").style["img"] = 'max-width: 40%; max-height: 40%;';
</script>
```

Comment: Can you not change the CSS or HTML directly? Using JS for styling is not a very good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's much better if you use classes for this purpose.

Please, try this solution:

```
<style>

.img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;    
}

.changesize { 
    max-width: 40%;
    max-height: 40%;
}

</style>

<div id="win" class="img">xyz</div>

<script>
    document.getElementById("win").className = "changesize";
</script>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this jQuery code to change the CSS of any element in the page with javascript:

```
$("#win img").css({
    "max-width":"40%",
    "max-height":"40%"
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TiagoMarinho/K48BL/)

You can also use pure JavaScript to do so, but you'll need to create an id to your `img` tag, and the code will look like this:

```
document.getElementById("#myImage").style.maxWidth = "40%";
document.getElementById("#myImage").style.maxHeight = "40%";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like below

```
$('#win img').css({'max-width':'40%','max-height': '40%;'});
```

Answer (score 0):

from your code it seems that you didnt completely understand how css selectors work.
the best answer i can give you is to direct you to http://www.w3schools.com/ to learn the basics first.

however, note that css selectors work that way:

- a selector that has a # prefix, refers to id.
- a selector that has a . prefix refers to class.
- a selector that has no prefix, refers to an element.

therefore your selector `#win img` selects `<img>` elements inside some element with `id="win"`.

 however, your div with id "win" doesnt have any `<img>` element inside of it.

also, `element.style` is a collection of the styling attributes of the element, and not a collection of styles, so when you call:

```
document.getElementById("win").style["img"] = 'max-width: 40%; max-height: 40%;';
```

what it actually means, is to find an element with id="win" and set its style's 'img' attribute to `'max-width: 40%; max-height: 40%;';`
basically what you did is equal to:

```
#win{
   img:max-width: 40%; max-height: 40%;
}
```

which makes no sense.

in order to select the `#win img` element, you need to use `querySelectorAll` as follows:

```
var myElements = document.querySelectorAll('#win img');
```

and then loop through the list you get and update their styling.

```
element.style["max-width"]= "40%";
element.style["max-height"]= "40%";
```

or since you have tagged your question as jQuery, you can use the jQuery selector and update them all at once:

```
$("#win img").css({
    max-width: ...
    max-height: ...
    width: ...
    height: ...
});
```